# Stub for Feign client for integration testing

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing, spring-cloud, wiremock, spring-cloud-feign

I have a spring cloud project with the following packaging structure

Controller (publishes Rest Endpoint)-->flow (business logic)-->service (calls Feign client with hysterix fallback setup )--> Feign client.

Auto-wiring is done in respective classes e.g. flow is auto-wired in controller and service is auto-wired in flow and so on.

I want to perform integration test, by calling the endpoint published by the controller. The problem is I don't have endpoint accessed by the feign client at the moment (neither original nor spring cloud contract stub is available).

How do I stub the call made by feign client in this case.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Spring Cloud WireMock support and set up an endpoint manually before the tests are called. In the feign configuration you can point manually to an IP and port. The problem is that this test is pretty much useless cause as a consumer you're mocking the producer.

UPDATE

You have a Feign client that will be used to call some external API. What you can do is you can use Spring Cloud WireMock (or just WireMock) to setup a mock of that API. Then you can teach WireMock to behave as you wish and assert whether your client works fine. The problem with such an approach is such that since you, as a client, are setting up the WireMock instance, you can teach it to behave in the way that has nothing to do with the real API. For example you state that if you send a request to endpoint /foo with a method GET then you should get back "BAR" in the response. Then you write a test where your client sends GET @ /foo and assert that BAR got properly returned. However that doesn't mean that the other API indeed has that endpoint. So this approach can give you false-positives. You can however use WireMock to assert whether you can properly react to faulty responses like malformed response etc.

In such cases, if you really want to check if you can communicate properly with an API that you don't control, is that you can write tests that will call that real API via a WireMock proxy, you record that traffic and convert it into stubs. You can watch about this more in my presentation here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZyHG-VOzPZg

Comment: Can you eleborate more this. I am struggling a bit to make integration tests work for my FeignClient with Spring Boot. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you Marcin for the update. I am also thinking about how to do testing. Would you recommend me a reference how to do end-to-end testing without mocks for such scenarios

Comment: You can read the spring cloud contract documentation https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-contract/2.2.2.RELEASE/reference/html/index.html all is described there. Can we mark this as answered?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I cannot mark it answered cause the option is not visible